# Exception - When the JVM runs out of memory, which exception will be thrown?

Tags: java, exception

**I am little bit confused**

1. MemoryBoundException
2. OutOfMemoryException
3. OutOfRangeException
4. NullReferenceException

I found in http://www.gkseries.com/ that the exception thrown when the JVM runs out of memory is OutOfMemoryException. I am not getting this properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which exception do you get?

Comment: None of them, should be an OutOfMemoryError. This is something different than an exception.

Comment: Is your code _really_ relying on such an error to be thrown?

Comment: You certainly are confused. You are asking about four exceptions, not one of which exists in the JRE, and you've posted a link that doesn't say what you said it does: it's just a front page. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

All choices are wrong since there is no such thing as an `OutOfMemoryException` - there's only `OutOfMemoryError`. While this might seem not much of a difference it might still matter:

`OutOfMemoryError` does not extend `Exception` but `Error`, so it might not be caught by a `catch (Exeption e)` clause (but catching generic Exceptions is bad style anyway, you should rather catch specific exceptions that you know you can handle).

There are several falours of `OutOfMemoryError` depending on which kind of resource the JVM is lacking - for example it might be out of heap-space, out of perm-gen (only up to java 7), unable to start a new thread.

Comment: Why is catching exceptions bad style? Can you pls post a link that explains.

Comment: Tx and I agree: catching *generic* exceptions is bad style.